# Vidyo issue: 'Call' process does not end when all participants leave, in mediabrige container

Tags: docker, vidyo

Whenever there is more than 1 mediabridge docker container running on my instance(server), the "Call" process inside the container doesn't end even after the last participant leaves the meeting.

I am using the following code for monitoring the 'Call' process

`docker exec <contaierId> pgrep -x call`

Meanwhile, it ends successfully when only one container is running on the server.

Use Case: 
If the user leaves the meeting without clicking the stop/leave button, then in this case I monitor the 'Call' process running in mediabridge container image.

If the call returns nothing then I transfer the file and stop+remove the container, this works perfectly fine when i have only one container running on the server.

Incase of more then one containers the 'Call' process ends only after 'Call' process in other container has stopped OR Max time limit is breached.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, I had a discussion with the Vidyo team, posting their reply here so that anybody else saves the trouble.

> it seems like the recording is bounded to endpoint ID rather to the
>   token. Endpoint ID is unique to the connected hardware. Have one
>   participant at the same time on a few conferences is an edge case and
>   out of usual behavior. At this point, it comes out of regular support
>   unless you will request this feature supported